# Automatically forwarding from Bastion to next server?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, bastion

We at work use Bastion in our VPC to connect to several private servers, I have set up aliases (ssh host aliases) to speed up the process of bouncing to the next server, but this is a slow process and many users end up catting our config to find the appropriate alias. I would like to figure out a way to be able to have our users be able to ssh / sftp through Bastion? Does anyone know an acceptable method? I looked briefly into mosh-server but am uncertain whether this is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming OpenSSH on Linux/MacOS. Putty likely offers something similar.

Tell your users to use the `ProxyCommand` in their ~/.ssh/config files:

```
cat ~/.ssh/config

Host  !bastion.example.com *.example.com 
   ProxyCommand ssh -q -a  user@gateway.example.com nc %h %p
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If you then try to connect to `test.example.com`, ssh will automatically tunnel this connection via `bastion.example.com`.

You can add endless flexibility to this if you like.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get right back to accepting, we just had a server outage =/ plus one and accepted, thank you for the prompt and clear answer